# Javascript onclick only works once

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

So I made this,

```
var Coin = document.getElementById("coin");

Coin.onclick = function() {
    Coin.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(1800deg)";
    Coin.style.MozTransform = "rotateY(1800deg)";
    Coin.style.msTransform = "rotateY(1800deg)";
    Coin.style.OTransform = "rotateY(1800deg)";
    Coin.style.transform = "rotateY(1800deg)";
}
```

Found at: https://jsfiddle.net/dkjufqn0/

And in it, a coin spins. However, it only fires once. The first time I click it. It doesn't fire again after. Help!

Comment: The event fires every time you click it, you should make the degree a variable and change it with every click.

Comment: It doesn't fires only once. It acutally fires every time you click it. It sets the rotation to 1800deg every time, that's it. So after the first time, you just can't notice the effect because the rotation is already set to 1800deg.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every time you click the coin it remains at the 1800 degrees, to rotate it on  each click you need to increment its degrees as in below example:

https://jsfiddle.net/dkjufqn0/1/

```js
var Coin = document.getElementById("coin");
var degrees = 0;
Coin.onclick = function() {
  degrees += 1800;
  console.log(degrees)
  Coin.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(" + degrees + "deg)";
  Coin.style.MozTransform = "rotateY(" + degrees + "deg)";
  Coin.style.msTransform = "rotateY(" + degrees + "deg)";
  Coin.style.OTransform = "rotateY(" + degrees + "deg)";
  Coin.style.transform = "rotateY(" + degrees + "deg)";
}
```

```css
body {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(500px);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.coin {
  background-image: url("http://coins.thefuntimesguide.com/images/blogs/presidential-dollar-coin-reverse-statue-of-liberty-public-domain.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: 2s linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<div class="coin" id="coin"></div>
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot. But I'd like to ask, what's with the "deg" at the end? Couldn't I have used rotateY(1800deg) instead of putting the degrees into a separate variable?

Comment: you might need to check your console for more clarification : `console.log("rotateY(" + degrees + "deg)")`

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about that?
place a console.log(in that handler to check it)

I think your code is fine, except the rotateY calls seem to do nothing after the first click because you always set it to the same value.